# AskTimeoutException during Embedded Kafka Unit testing Akka Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I am working on **akka** with **Kafka** and writing test cases for my Kafka Consumer.
I used Embedded Kafka for unit testing.

When i try to run my test case everything goes fine, but in last following Exception occurred:

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://testActor/system/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-1-mapAsyncUnordered#-2130769]] after [1000 ms]. Message of type [akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$Snapshot$] was sent by [Actor[akka://testActor/system/StreamSupervisor-0#-867168141]]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.

at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:675)
at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:696)
at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:202)
at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:875)
at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:113)
at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:107)
at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:873)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:334)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:285)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:289)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my code.

My Test method is:

```
@Test
public void publishMessage() {

    final TestKit probe = new TestKit(system);
    final Config config = system.settings().config().getConfig("akka.kafka.producer");
    ActorRef childMaker = probe.getTestActor();

    final ProducerSettings<String, String> producerSettings =
            ProducerSettings.create(config, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer())
                    .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers);

    Source.range(1, 10)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .map(value -> new ProducerRecord<>(topic, 0, "key1", value))
            .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings), materializer);

    new EventFilter(Logging.Info.class, system)
            .occurrences(1)
            .matches("Starting up Consumer:")
            .matches("Consumer Started:")
            .intercept(() -> TestActorRef
                    .create(system, KafkaConsumerPlainExternalSource.props(new RequestRegisterConsumer(system,
                            config, bootstrapServers, groupId, topic, (byte) 0, childMaker))));

}
```

My KafkaConsumer Class looks like:

```
public class KafkaConsumerPlainExternalSource extends AbstractLoggingActor {

private static RequestRegisterConsumer consumerConf;

static Props props(RequestRegisterConsumer consumerConf) {
    return Props.create(KafkaConsumerPlainExternalSource.class, consumerConf);
}

public KafkaConsumerPlainExternalSource(RequestRegisterConsumer consumerConf) {
    KafkaConsumerPlainExternalSource.consumerConf = consumerConf;
}

@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder().build();
}

@Override
public void preStart() {

    log().info("Starting up Consumer: " + self().path().toString());

    //Update
akka.kafka.javadsl.Consumer.plainExternalSource(consumer, Subscriptions
                .assignment(new TopicPartition(consumerConf.getTopic(), consumerConf.getTopicPartition())))
                .mapAsync(10, Consumer :: consume)
                .to(Sink.ignore())
                .run(ActorMaterializer.create(consumerConf.getActorSystem()));
    log().info("Consumer Started: " + self().path().toString());
}
```

}

My application.conf file is:

```
>    akka { 
>   loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener] 
>     test {
>     timefactor = 1.0
>     filter-leeway = 10s
>     calling-thread-dispatcher {
>       type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
>     }   }   kafka.producer {//producer conf} }
```

When i add a sleep of 10 sec in last of my test case than my test runs fine. I could not find the root cause of this Exception.

Comment: Your example doesn't include the code for the code.  Given the reference to `Producer.plainSink` I assume you're using Alpakka Kafka, but I don't see an Alpakka Kafka consumer source.  https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html

Comment: I am using **plainExternalSource** to consume the data from Kafka. I also update the question for your reference.

Comment: I don't think all of your Consumer code is implemented, but I suspect that you're not waiting for the stream to complete before the test ends.  You're receiving an ask timeout because Alpakka Kafka is in the process of being shut down before some internal implementation can receive its ACK. Add criteria to complete the stream (i.e. a `takeWhile`), and then add blocking for the `CompletionStage` returned by `.run`.